# How to specific key value pairs from this array to a new array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, key-value

array

```
[{
    "key":"Passed",
    "values":[[date1,time1],[date2,time2]]
},{
    "key":"Failed",
    "values":[[date3,time3],[date4,time4]]
}]
```

Say i want to copy key:failed and values [date3,time3] to a new array, how do i do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow :). Am i correct in assuming you want to retrieve only the first `[date3,time3]` for each `"Failed"` array item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will want to identify the object in the array by it's key.
Lets assume you array is stored in a variable called `mylist`

```
var error = mylist.find(function(item){ return item.key === 'Failed'; });
```

now assuming you have a new array:

```
var failed = []; // your new array
failed.push({
    key: error.key,
    values: error.values[0] // assuming you only want the first value
});
```

There may be a better application for this though. If you could provide more context around what you want achieve.

**EDIT**:

If you are looking to grab every failed result from the array and group them into a subset you may want user the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method to do the following.

```
var failed = mylist.reduce(function(mem, item) {
    if(item.key === 'Failed'){
        var transformed = {
            key: error.key,
            values: error.values[0]
        };
        mem.push(transform)
    }
    return mem;
}, []);
```

Comment: No, i want only the dates between a specific range inside the same array.I am not sure the above code does that.

Comment: @ParvathyGeetha No it doesn't but I can edit it to do so. It's helpful if you can explain this in your question. Can you provide an actual example of the data in the values array.

Answer (score 0):

Using just JavaScript

```
var newArray = [];

for(var i=0; i<=array.length; i++){
 if (array[i]['key'] === "Failed"){
    newArray.push(array[i]);
  }
}
```

`newArray` contains all the failed items.